# Is there a way to set tabs of a Notebook below one another?

Tags: python, user-interface, tabs, tkinter, ttk

So far when using the `ttk.Notebook` widget, but I am unable to set tabs below one another, they keep piling up eastward.

Is there a way to set them to stack somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, please check this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('lefttab.TNotebook', tabposition='wn')

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root, style='lefttab.TNotebook')

f1 = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='red', width=200, height=200)
f2 = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='blue', width=200, height=200)

notebook.add(f1, text='Frame 1')
notebook.add(f2, text='Frame 2')

notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360251/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

For reference - Yes

See the code in the following [top right tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822553/align-tabs-from-right-to-left-using-ttk-notebook-widget)

And use `'wn'` to force the tabs to stack in the top left and downwards

Comment: Please try to include the actual code sample in the answer as well as the link.  I know the link is to a SO page but it is easier if the code is within the answer.