# Align tabs from right to left using ttk.Notebook widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

I want to align tabs (panes) inside a [`ttk.Notebook`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttk-notebook) widget from right to left (the default is from left to right). How might this be done?

Below is my current code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(300, 300)
root.geometry("1000x700")

box = ttk.Notebook(root, width=1000, height=650)

tab1 = tk.Frame(root)
tab2 = tk.Frame(root)
tab3 = tk.Frame(root)

box.add(tab1, text="tab1")
box.add(tab2, text="tab2")
box.add(tab3, text="tab3")

box.pack(side=tk.TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: To clarify, you want the tabs "tab1", "tab2", and "tab3" appear in that order, but on the top-right corner?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is actually a style option for this - **tabposition**.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(300, 300)
root.geometry("1000x700")

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('TNotebook', tabposition='ne') #'ne' as in compass direction

box = ttk.Notebook(root, width=1000, height=650)

tab1 = tk.Frame(root)
tab2 = tk.Frame(root)
tab3 = tk.Frame(root)

box.add(tab1, text="tab1")
box.add(tab2, text="tab2")
box.add(tab3, text="tab3")

box.pack(side=tk.TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you ...I thought there is no way to do so since I searched for days to resolve this problem with no luck..until you answerd the question..

Comment: Anyone looking for full width tabs aligned center, use `tabposition=tk.NSEW`

Answer (score 1):

In Oblivion's line:

```
s.configure('TNotebook', tabposition='ne')
```

the 'ne' bit can be:

```
nw => above (north) and to the left (west)
ne => above and to the right (east)
en => to the right (east), at the top
es => to the right (east), at the bottom
se => below (south) and to the right (east)
sw => below (south) and to the left (west)
ws => to the left (west) and to the bottom (south)
wn => to the left (west) and at top
```

'nw' is, I guess, the more common one, but an application may require it otherwise.