# How to make it so the close button on the ttk notebook tab is specific and does not appear for all tabs

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I have a `tkinter.ttk.notebook` in my program that has [close buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458337/is-there-a-way-to-add-close-buttons-to-tabs-in-tkinter-ttk-notebook) for all tabs that are created in it.

But I want that the first tab created shall not bear a close button acting like a welcome tab that cannot be closed by the user.

I have a ttk notebook wherein I have a welcome tab which I always want to be there and not have the close buttons, but I also want the other tabs to have the close button. Also The close buttons I am talking about is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458337/is-there-a-way-to-add-close-buttons-to-tabs-in-tkinter-ttk-notebook).

So if there is a way to make the close buttons specific for only some tabs and not all, then it might help.
Unfortunately the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458337/is-there-a-way-to-add-close-buttons-to-tabs-in-tkinter-ttk-notebook) from where I picked up the logic/code for the close buttons does not mention any way to have close buttons for some tabs and not for the others.

My code -:

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk

class CustomNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
    """A ttk Notebook with close buttons on each tab"""

    __initialized = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.__initialized:
            self.__initialize_custom_style()
            self.__inititialized = True

        kwargs["style"] = "CustomNotebook"
        ttk.Notebook.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self._active = None

        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_close_press, True)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_close_release)

    def on_close_press(self, event):
        """Called when the button is pressed over the close button"""

        element = self.identify(event.x, event.y)

        if "close" in element:
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            self.state(['pressed'])
            self._active = index
            return "break"

    def on_close_release(self, event):
        """Called when the button is released"""
        if not self.instate(['pressed']):
            return

        element =  self.identify(event.x, event.y)
        if "close" not in element:
            # user moved the mouse off of the close button
            return

        index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))

        if self._active == index:
            self.forget(index)
            self.event_generate("<<NotebookTabClosed>>")

        self.state(["!pressed"])
        self._active = None

    def __initialize_custom_style(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        self.images = (
            tk.PhotoImage("img_close", data='''
                R0lGODlhCAAIAMIBAAAAADs7O4+Pj9nZ2Ts7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7OyH+EUNyZWF0ZWQg
                d2l0aCBHSU1QACH5BAEKAAQALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMVGDBEA0qNJyGw7AmxmuaZhWEU
                5kEJADs=
                '''),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_closeactive", data='''
                R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2cbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxiH5BAEKAAQALAAA
                AAAIAAgAAAMVGDBEA0qNJyGw7AmxmuaZhWEU5kEJADs=
                '''),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_closepressed", data='''
                R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAOUqKv9mZtnZ2Ts7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7OyH+EUNyZWF0ZWQg
                d2l0aCBHSU1QACH5BAEKAAQALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMVGDBEA0qNJyGw7AmxmuaZhWEU
                5kEJADs=
            ''')
        )

        style.element_create("close", "image", "img_close",
                            ("active", "pressed", "!disabled", "img_closepressed"),
                            ("active", "!disabled", "img_closeactive"), border=8, sticky='')
        style.layout("CustomNotebook", [("CustomNotebook.client", {"sticky": "nswe"})])
        style.layout("CustomNotebook.Tab", [
            ("CustomNotebook.tab", {
                "sticky": "nswe",
                "children": [
                    ("CustomNotebook.padding", {
                        "side": "top",
                        "sticky": "nswe",
                        "children": [
                            ("CustomNotebook.focus", {
                                "side": "top",
                                "sticky": "nswe",
                                "children": [
                                    ("CustomNotebook.label", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                    ("CustomNotebook.close", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                ]
                        })
                    ]
                })
            ]
        })
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    notebook = CustomNotebook(width=200, height=200)
    notebook.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    
    welcome_frame = tk.Frame(notebook)
    # I want this tab to have no close button
    notebook.add(welcome_frame, text = 'Welcome')
    
    for color in ("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "violet"):
        frame = tk.Frame(notebook, background=color)
        notebook.add(frame, text=color)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It seems that it is not possible to do so, as you cannot "style a tab individually": https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.tcl/c/rthP-Hk0UPU/m/cpiFqJzPCQAJ

Comment: Hmm thanks guess then I would have to figure out something else btw is it possible that well the close button atleast becomes greyed out for certain tabs and does not get clicked maybe we can still keep the close button but disable it somehow?