# Is there any way to add minimise button so tht it minimises in frame and close buttons to tabs in tkinter.ttk.Notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tabs, ttk

I hav a multiple frames in a window I wana add tabs and make them minimise and maximise and close  inside a. Frame when u need so is thr any way to do

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, you can find tips about how to improve your question on the [How to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question is way too broad at the moment. Mind that SO is not a code writing service so please share what you have tried and explain in more detail what is not working and where you are stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to add close buttons to tabs in tkinter.ttk.Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458337/is-there-a-way-to-add-close-buttons-to-tabs-in-tkinter-ttk-notebook)