# Closing Tabs with an "x" on tkinter Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs

I would like to know, if there's a way to be able to close a tab in tkinter Notebook by clicking on an "x" next to the tab title. However I don't want to apply this to all tabs in the notebook. I want some tabs to be fixed in the window.

Here's a demonstration of what I have in mind: (please click the link, unfortunately I still can't post an image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnOOY.gif

And that's the code..

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

def open_second():
    def open_2():
        if pass_box.get() == "123":
            tabs.add(second_tab, text='2nd X')
            tabs.select(second_tab)

        pass_window.destroy()

    pass_window = Tk()
    pass_window.geometry("200x100")
    pass_window.resizable(False, False)

    pass_label = Label(pass_window, text="Enter Pass:")
    pass_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)

    pass_box = Entry(pass_window, show="*")
    pass_box.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

    pass_button = Button(pass_window, text="Enter", command=open_2)
    pass_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, anchor=CENTER)


root = tk.Tk()
root.state("zoomed")

# Create tabs
tabs = ttk.Notebook(root)
tabs.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

first_tab = ttk.Frame(tabs)
tabs.add(first_tab, text='1st')

second_tab = ttk.Frame(tabs)

menubar = Menu(root)
option = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
option.add_command(label="2nd Tab", command=open_second)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Option", menu=option)


root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This question has already been answered 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39459376/16513476).

Comment: @LBJ thank you! unfortunately the code in the answer applies this functions to all tabs.. I still need help on how to apply it to specific tabs only